# Send mail using SendGrid in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I'm sending confirmation mail using SendGrid to confirm email but 
ApiKey always null

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{

    var ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKeyFromSendGrid");
    var client = new SendGridClient(ApiKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "Any Name");
    var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    var to = new EmailAddress(message.Destination, "Any Name");
    var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
    var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
    var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    return response;

}
```

where is the error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hObav.jpg)

Comment: It means an environment variable with such key doesn't exist. Check that the key is correct. Debug.

Comment: How to check if variable exist ?

Comment: Seems strange to use an environment variable for this. Why not store the value in your .config file?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the recovery of the environment variable:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKeyFromSendGrid");
```

The `ApiKeyFromSendGrid` exist?

See if these questions and answers help you to retrieve the environment variable correctly:

[How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185208/5522115)

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable won't find variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12754884/5522115)

Comment: @OmarSeleim Ok, but the image shows the key being displayed on the site. Did you set it as the environment variable? In your system does it exist?

Comment: API KEYS begin with "SG." Please see my answer above.

Comment: I will use as 
    var ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SG.Tob9Zs...-....");
or like 
    var ApiKey = ("SG.Tob9Zs...-....");

??

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong value for the API Key. You are using the API Key ID. You'll probably need to create a new key if you didn't store the original key value somewhere.

See [SendGrid API Key not working. "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789622/sendgrid-api-key-not-working-the-provided-authorization-grant-is-invalid-expi/34798357#34798357)